# Select rows with similar value in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table called trades and has a field session id. The table has specific rows with a similar session id. This reason some rows have a similar session id is that when a trade is placed, it takes an existing session id.

I now want to select rows with similar sessions ids and do something with it.

This is my first query that lists all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM trades 
where trade_session_status="DONE" AND 
      trade_profit_worker_status="UNDONE"
```

I have tried this query as well

```
SELECT * FROM trades 
where trade_session_status="DONE" AND 
      trade_profit_worker_status="UNDONE" 
order BY(session_id)
```

I have looked at the distinct queries and came up with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT session_id,id 
FROM trades 
WHERE trade_session_status="DONE" AND 
      trade_profit_worker_status="UNDONE"  
ORDER BY session_id
```

The #2 and #3 queries all return the same number of rows. My question is,will the #2 and #3 queries always return the rows with distinct session_id without leaving any rows out?.

Comment: DISTINCT works on row level,  so a `SELECT DISTINCT x, y from t` will get the unique values of (x,y).  If you want to know the session_id's that are used more than once, then you could `GROUP BY session_id` with a `HAVING count(*) > 1`.  But if you want to have complete rows of only those where the session_id is used in other rows? Then I'd suggest to use an `EXISTS`.

Comment: if i have the having count(session_id) > 1 that will list only 1 row in my case. I want to list all rows with a similar session_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that you could use an EXISTS for this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM trades t
WHERE trade_session_status = 'DONE' 
  AND trade_profit_worker_status = 'UNDONE'
  AND EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT 1
        FROM trades d
        WHERE d.trade_session_status = 'DONE' 
          AND d.trade_profit_worker_status = 'UNDONE'
          AND d.session_id = t.session_id
          AND d.id <> t.id
      );
```

Note that the criteria for trade_session_status & trade_profit_worker_status are also used in the query for the EXISTS. I don't know if that's needed for your purpose, so remove them if that's not what you expect.  But you get the idea.

Another way is to inner join to a sub-query with the duplicate session_id's.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM trades t
JOIN 
(
   SELECT session_id
   FROM trades
   WHERE trade_session_status = 'DONE' 
     AND trade_profit_worker_status = 'UNDONE'
   GROUP BY session_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) d ON d.session_id = t.session_id
WHERE t.trade_session_status = 'DONE'
  AND t.trade_profit_worker_status = 'UNDONE';
```